# Primefaces tabview: set Active Index after some counting

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I've got a tab view that contains four tabs and three commandButtons(count,add to Table, export to Word) over them.

I input some text data in first tab, some numeric data in second tab, then when I am pressing first commandButton(count), my programm do some countings, but I can't set Active Index on third Tab where I show result of counting.

```
<h:form id="dataForm1" prependId="false">
   <div>
      <p:commandButton id="count" update="tbv" process="tbv:tab1 tbv:tab2" />
      <p:commandButton id="addToWord" .... />
      <p:commandButton id="exportToWord" ... />
   </div
   <div>
      <p:growl id="growlm" showDetail="true" /> 
    <p:tabView activeIndex="#{disableTag.activeTabIndex}" id="tbv" tabChangeListener="#{disableTag.onTabChange}">
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{disableTag.onTabChange}" update=":dataForm1:growlm" />
          <p:tab id="tab1">some text data </p:tab>
          <p:tab id="tab2">some numeric data</p:tab>
          <p:tab id="tab3">result of counting from tab2</p:tab>
          <p:tab id="tab4">table</p:tab>
     </p:tabView>
```

Backing bean
        public int getActiveTabIndex() {
        return activeTabIndex;
    }

```
public void setActiveTabIndex(int activeTabIndex) {
    this.activeTabIndex = activeTabIndex;
}

public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
    TabView tv = (TabView) event.getComponent();
    this.setActiveTabIndex(tv.getActiveIndex());
    System.out.println("###### ACtive tab: "+activeTabIndex);
}
```

But it is not working for me, do you have any idea: how i can set third tab activeIndex=2 after countings?

Comment: Your commandbutton which has id="count" is not bound to any of the backing bean function. you can bind it to a backing bean function which sets the activeTabIndex.

Comment: You have to update the whole tabview on `tabChange` so that the active tab gets updated in the view.

Comment: What exactly happens when u click the button? What is the scope of your BackingBean? Try to log the activeIndex value inside setActiveTabIndex method.

Comment: Your code appears to be redundant: Why do you need to set the active index, to the index of the already active tab?

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to get it:

**// View**

```
    <h:form id="yourForm">
        ...
        <p:commandButton value="Go to tab 3" action="#{yourBackingBean.doSomeCounting('2')}"
                         update="tabView"/>
        ...
    </h:form>
```

then inside your counting method:

**// BackingBean**

```
public void doSomeCounting(String tabIndex){
    // your counting logic
    try {
        activeTabIndex = Integer.parseInt(tabIndex);
        System.out.println("showing tab: "+activeTabIndex);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
}
```

If I understand correctly what you're intending.